# VB.Net doesn't recognise an active MySQL transaction

Tags: mysql, vb.net, transactions, information-schema

I'm writing an app in VB.Net that works via MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver with data stored in a MySQL database. Trying to simulate concurrent access, I have MySQL Workbench open and my app.

In Workbench I lock some records:

```
begin;
select * from tbltest where test like 'test%' for update;
```

In my app I query the MySQL database:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.innodb_trx;
```

And since there is an active transaction, I correctly get back '1'.

I rollback the transaction in Workbench and try the same the other way round. This time I start the transaction in my app, with exactly the same SQL code:

```
begin;
select * from tbltest where test like 'test%' for update;
```

But when I then query *information_schema.innodb_trx* in Workbench, I get back '0': Workbench doesn't find an active transaction.

When I change the code to the following, though, Workbench as well as my app correctly find an active transaction:

```
begin;
select * from tbltest for update;
```

How can it be that in the first case my VB.Net app doesn't find a transaction, while in the second case it does? Could there be a more general problem with the MySQL ODBC driver?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not try the .net provider for MySQL. I believe there is a Nuget package.

Comment: Thanks Mary. This is an older application and I don't know how much work it would be to change everything from ODBC to the .NET provider. Do you have experiences with it? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated projects all the way back to DAO and it has always made things easier. Can you pull out a small portion of the project to a new project and try a sample with the MySQL provider? VB.net does not really have anything to do with it. It is the ODBC provider in ADO.net.

Comment: You were right, Mary. I changed from ODBC to the .Net MySQL provider, and the problems are gone. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it!